# Displaying data from a linked table and displaying it as a list with HTML/PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have three tables.

```
students
studentID | FirstName | LastName | Email | Form  

course
CCode | Title  

courseenrolement
courseenrolementid | studentID | ccode | complete | scode
```

With the website, I have a page where I can view all the current `enrolements` and I wish to be able to view the list displaying the `first name, surname and course title`. I know I could do it with the following SQL (for the names):

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM student, courseenrolement 
WHERE courseenrolement.studentID = student.studentID
```

But I am unsure how to get this to work using HTML/PHP. At present I only know how to display the `studentID and CCode` from the `courseenrolement` table using the following code:

```
<ul>
  <?php foreach ($courseenrolements as $ce): ?>
    <li>
      <form action="" method="post">
        <div>
          <?php htmlout($ce['studentID']); ?>
          <?php htmlout($ce['CCode']); ?>
          <input type="hidden" name="courseenrolementid" value="<?php
              echo $ce['courseenrolementid']; ?>">
          <input type="submit" name="action" value="Edit">
          <input type="submit" name="action" value="Delete">
        </div>
      </form>
    </li>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

which displays this:

[image: output]

But I would like the `names and course title`. I managed to get it to show the `names` etc in the dropdown on the 'Add new' form, so I would assume it will be similar, but just unsure on how exactly. Thanks in advance

Comment: It wont let me, it keeps saying there is apparently incorrectly formatted code when there is not. And you dont need my code to simply answer a question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you're not using a web development framework. That being the case, check out PHP's `PDO` library, which lets you make portable database queries in a structured manner.

Regardless of whether you check out the PDO library, what you need here is to expand your query with a `JOIN`, and select the columns you want. Google for simple examples of `JOIN` queries, because your use-case seems pretty simple. You can then iterate over the result set resource with a `for` loop, and output data to HTML as necessary.